# General equivalence of differential equation and difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

Let $g$ be a continuous function (not necessarily smooth). Let $\Delta g=\frac{g(x+\Delta x)-g(x)}{\Delta x}$.

Consider the difference equation:

> $F(\Delta\Delta g,\Delta g,g)=K$

**Question**: Under which assumptions, would the difference equation to have the same solutions as the ODE $F(f'',f',f)=K$?

"Assumption" means, for example, some additional restrictions putting on $\Delta x$ and $g$.

Comment: Is $\Delta x$ fixed? If $g$ is not affine then $\Delta g$ will depend on $\Delta x$ at each point $x$.

Comment: By guess is to let $\Delta x$ be very small, so we would have a generalized definition of "derivative" without requiring $g$ to be differentiable.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think the new update might reflect your meaning

Comment: So what you effectively have is the explicit Euler method for this implicit second order DE. The question of convergence thus has two parts, the implicit function theorem for local solvability for $f''$ and then the convergence of the Euler method. If $f$ is vector-valued, you get further exciting possibilities. If $F$ is only partially solvable (positive, but not full rank), you can get DAE systems (requires locally constant differentiation index).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Many thanks for suggestions. By DE do you mean difference equation or differential equation?

Comment: Usually the differential equation.